# Wildfly 10.1.0 IllegalStateException - UT000010 Session is Invalid

Tags: java, jsf, jboss, wildfly

Running JSF 2.0 on Wildfly 10.1.0 in Docker. Am sometimes seeing 504 Gateway Timeout even though session timeout is 30 minutes by default and session has not yet been 30 minutes?. I am seeing sometimes a specific session is being timed out early(17 minutes instead of 30 for instance) but for all other sessions, they time out automatically after 30 min of inactivity.

Am puzzled on how sessions are being ended prematurely? It is extremely hard to debug as this issue is intermittent and sporadic. Is this a Wildfly bug or internal application code issue? We are calling session.invalidate() for the HTTPServlet API when a user clicks the logout button. Would appreciate any input from JSF/Wildfly gurus!

Comment: 504 gateway timeout sounds like you try to request sm,ething on a remote server from yours. Security/authentication related?

Comment: Maybe the session gets destroyed then if this fails

Comment: Yes session is destroyed. I have a HTTPSessionListenerImpl which logs a message when the session is destroyed. I am puzzled why that session is ending before 30 min?

Comment: As result of the 504 error from a remote system?

Comment: This is a 504 error for a web app deployed on AWS. I am unable to reproduce the error locally. We have seen 504 happen occasionally.